# Adding a record to a dynamic table (using AngularJS) reloads the entire page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, reload, dynamic-tables

The table footer is used to add a new record to the table. After adding by clicking button, the new record is actually added to the table body but up to a second, after that the entire page is reloaded and the inserted record disappears.

- Table is created correctly from the prepared data array.
- Deleting records works fine.

Where can I have a problem? I don't want to have page reloads.

Table:

```
<table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nazwa tchnologii</th>
                <th>Poziom zaawansowania</th>
                <th>-</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <!--Text for new record-->
                <th><input type="text" ng-model="nazwaTechnologii" class="form-control"></th>
                <!--Button to add-->
                <th><button ng-click="dodaj()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Dodaj!</button></th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>

            <tbody id="cialoTabeli">
            <tr ng-repeat="technologia in technologie track by technologia.id" id="{{technologia.id}}">
                <td>{{technologia.nazwa}}</td>
                <!--Button to remove-->
                <td><input type="button" ng-click="usunTechnologie(technologia.id)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Usuń!</input></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
 </table>
```

Piece of code JavaScript/AngularJS:

```
var indeks = 5;
$scope.dodaj = function () {
      $scope.technologie.push({ 'id': ++indeks, 'nazwa': $scope.nazwaTechnologii});
      $scope.nazwaTechnologii='';
};

$scope.technologie = [   //prepared values
    {"id":1,"nazwa":"C++"},
    {"id":2,"nazwa":"java"},
    {"id":3,"nazwa":"Python"},
    {"id":4,"nazwa":"C"}
];
```

Comment: Can we see more of the HTML and controller code? I tried your code in a plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/gVdUeAKX8WAu3w0MCW21) and it seems to work fine, so there is likely something else going wrong - likely that you have all of this inside a form and are accidentally submitting the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Specifications) :

> **type**
>   The type of the button. Possible values are: submit: The button
>   submits the form data to the server. **This is the default if the
>   attribute is not specified**, or if the attribute is dynamically
>   changed to an empty or invalid value.

Means you need to set the button `type` to `button` in order to prevent the page from being "submitted" :

```html
<button type="button" ng-click="dodaj()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Dodaj!</button>
```